# here me to do this wheel of fortune I want to click button outsite to spin wheel

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to try click any button outside of wheel to spin wheel but not work how to do, help me please
I use yarn add vue-fortune-wheel@~1
here is my nuxt js version 2 and ui vuetify ,
my problem I want to click the button outsite to spin wheel only , because I want to check any values if true have to spin wheel if false have to stop wheel
the spin Wheel button it not work , please me if any body know thank you

here my code:

```
<template>
  <v-row>
    <v-col cols="12">
    <v-btn @click="spinWheel">Spin Wheel</v-btn>
      <FortuneWheel
        style="width: 500px; max-width: 100%"
        type="image"
        :useWeight="true"
        :verify="canvasVerify"
        :prizeId="prizeId"
        :angleBase="-30"
        :duration="6000"
        :timingFun="`cubic-bezier(0,0,.58,1)`"
        :prizes="prizesImage"
        @rotateStart="onImageRotateStart"
        @rotateEnd="onRotateEnd"
      >
        <template #wheel>
          <img
            src="/wheel.png"
            style="width: 100%; transform: rotateZ(-90deg)"
          />
        </template>
        <template #button>
          <img src="/button.png" style="width: 180px" />
        </template>
      </FortuneWheel>
      <div class="d-flex rounded-circle" style="width: 500px">
        <v-btn
          class="btn"
          v-for="(item, idx) in prizesCanvas"
          :key="idx"
          :style="{ background: item.bgColor }"
          @click="onChangePrize(item.id)"
        >
          {{ item.name }}
        </v-btn>
      </div>
      <div class="wheel-result">
        current 100%
        <span
          class="px-10"
          :style="{ background: prizeRes.bgColor, border: '1px solid white' }"
          >{{ prizeRes.name }}</span
        >
      </div>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</template>

<script>
import FortuneWheel from "vue-fortune-wheel";
import "vue-fortune-wheel/lib/vue-fortune-wheel.css";

// Define onImageRotateStart function outside the component
function onImageRotateStart(rotate) {
  rotate();
}

export default {
  components: {
    FortuneWheel,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      canvasVerify: true,
      prizeId: 0,
      canvasOptions: {
        borderWidth: 6,
        borderColor: "#584b43",
      },
      prizesCanvas: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "Green",
          value: "Green's value",
          bgColor: "#4CAF50",
          color: "#ffffff",
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Red",
          value: "Red's value",
          bgColor: "#dd3832",
          color: "#ffffff",
        },
      ],
      prizesImage: [
        {
          id: 1,
          value: "green's value",
          weight: 1,
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          value: "Red's value",
          weight: 0,
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    prizeRes() {
      const result =
        this.prizesCanvas.find((item) => item.id === this.prizeId) ||
        this.prizesCanvas[0];
      return result;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    spinWheel() {
    this.onImageRotateStart(() => {
      // Any additional actions after spinning
    });
  },
  onImageRotateStart(rotate) {
    rotate();
  },
    onChangePrize(prizeId) {
      this.prizeId = prizeId;
    },
    onRotateEnd(prize) {
      alert(prize.value);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Tried this one? https://github.com/XiaoLin1995/vue-fortune-wheel/issues/14#issuecomment-1546002197

Comment: Alternatively, you can also implement it by yourself with GSAP: https://gsap.com/docs/v3/Plugins/Draggable/